# How to get well-formed table from comm?

Tags: comm

I want to use the output of `comm` in other table parsers. However it seems like it produces inconsistently delimited rows.

For example:

```
$ comm <(echo "1\n2") <(echo "2\n3") | bat -A --style=plain
1␊
├──┤├──┤2␊
├──┤3␊
```

Because it's not padding with remaining tabs, I can't convert it to a CSV:

```
$ comm <(echo "1\n2") <(echo "2\n3") | tr \\t ,
1
,,2
,3
```

And can't ingest it as tab-delimited either:

```
$ comm <(echo "1\n2") <(echo "2\n3") | xsv input -d \\t
1
CSV error: record 1 (line: 2, byte: 2): found record with 3 fields, but the previous record has 1 fields
```

Is there a way to make `comm` produce a properly formatted table? The options I can see seem like more work than they should be:

- Replace with a regex
- Print each column separately

Comment: @Quasímodo Since `comm` does not appear to handle tabs in the input, we might as well rule them out. It would be nice if both the tabs and commas were escaped properly though.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
$ comm <(echo "1\n2") <(echo "2\n3")  | awk -F'\t' -v OFS=, '{NF=3;print}'
1,,
,,2
,3,
```

Where `awk` forces the `N`umber of `F`ields to be 3 and converts from an input `F`ield separator of TAB to an `O`utput `F`ield `S`eparator of `,`.

While it works with gawk, mawk or busybox awk, it doesn't work with the original nawk though where changing `NF` apparently doesn't cause the record to be regenerated with the new OFS. Alternatively, you could do instead:

```
$ comm <(echo "1\n2") <(echo "2\n3")  | awk -F'\t' -v OFS=, '{$3=$3;print}'
1,,
,,2
,3,
```

Which should work in any modern `awk`, and also guarantees the output has *at least* 3 fields (for the cases where input files to `comm` contain TAB characters).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with a regex solution, although it's not pretty:

```
$ comm <(echo "1\n2") <(echo "2\n3") | sed -E 's/^\t\t([^\t]*)$|^\t([^\t]*)$|^([^\t]*)$/\3,\2,\1/'
1,,
,,2
,3,
```

This will not work if your input either has tabs or commas in it.

Comment: I'll wait to see if anyone has a better answer.